# How can I find all documents in elasticsearch that contain a number in a certain field?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-mapping

I have a `keyword` type'd field that can contain either a number or a string.  If the field does not contain any letters, I would like to hit on that document.  How can I do this?

My index mapping looks like:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "Entry": {
      "properties": {
        "testField": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My documents look like this:

```
{
  "testField":"123abc"
}
```

or

```
{
  "testField": "456789"
}
```

I've tried the query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "gte": 0,
      "lte": 2000000
    }
  }
}
```

but it stills hits on `123abc`.  How can I design this so that I only hit on the documents with a number in that particular field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another more optimal option for achieving exactly what you want. You can leverage the [ingest API pipelines](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest-processors.html) and using a [`script` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/script-processor.html) you can create another numeric field at indexing time that you can then use more efficiently at search time.

The ingestion pipeline below contains a single `script` processor which will create another field called `numField` that will only contain numeric values.

```
POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
  "pipeline": {
    "processors": [
      {
        "script": {
          "source": """
          ctx.numField = /\D/.matcher(ctx.testField).replaceAll("");
          """
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
    {
      "_source": {
        "testField": "123"
      }
    },
    {
      "_source": {
        "testField": "abc123"
      }
    },
    {
      "_source": {
        "testField": "123abc"
      }
    },
    {
      "_source": {
        "testField": "abc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Simulating this pipeline with 4 different documents having a mix of alphanumeric content, will yield this:

```
{
  "docs" : [
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_index" : "_index",
        "_type" : "_type",
        "_id" : "_id",
        "_source" : {
          "numField" : "123",
          "testField" : "123"
        },
        "_ingest" : {
          "timestamp" : "2019-05-09T04:14:51.448Z"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_index" : "_index",
        "_type" : "_type",
        "_id" : "_id",
        "_source" : {
          "numField" : "123",
          "testField" : "abc123"
        },
        "_ingest" : {
          "timestamp" : "2019-05-09T04:14:51.448Z"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_index" : "_index",
        "_type" : "_type",
        "_id" : "_id",
        "_source" : {
          "numField" : "123",
          "testField" : "123abc"
        },
        "_ingest" : {
          "timestamp" : "2019-05-09T04:14:51.448Z"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_index" : "_index",
        "_type" : "_type",
        "_id" : "_id",
        "_source" : {
          "numField" : "",
          "testField" : "abc"
        },
        "_ingest" : {
          "timestamp" : "2019-05-09T04:14:51.448Z"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

After indexing your documents [using this pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html), you can run your range query on `numField` instead of `testField`. Compared to the other solution (sorry @Kamal), it will shift the scripting burden to run only once per document at indexing time, instead of everytime on every document at search time.

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "numField": {
        "gte": 0,
        "lte": 2000000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, Elasticsearch does not have a direct solution for this.

Instead you would need to write a [Script Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html). Below is what you are looking for:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "lang": "painless", 
              "source": """
                  try{           
                    String temp = doc['testField'].value;
                    int a = Integer.parseInt(temp);
                    if(a instanceof Integer)
                      return true;
                  }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                    return false;
                  }
              """
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!